# Check if a date is in an interval defined by partial/periodic dates

Tags: c++, algorithm

I can define an interval with `start` and `end` in the format `YYMMDD`, but they can also be partial/periodic - meaning some elements (day, month or year) can be left blank.

For example, `start = "  1115"` and `end = "  0115"` the interval is 15th nov to 15th jan every year.

I want to check if a non-partial date is in the interval.

```cpp
int compareParial(const char* first, const char* second)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        if (first[i] != ' ' && second[i] != ' ' && first[i] != second[i])
            return first[i] > second[i] ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool isDateInInterval(const char* start, const char* end, const char* searchDate)
{
    int firstCompare = compareParial(start, searchDate);
    int endCompare = compareParial(end, searchDate);

    if (firstCompare <= 0 && endCompare >= 0)
        return true;

    // the date can still be in the interval if the start of the interval is in one year, but end in the next year
    bool switched = 0 < compareParial(start, end);
    if (switched && (firstCompare <= 0) != (endCompare >= 0))
       return true;

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha << isDateInInterval("  1115", "  0115", "251110") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any gaps in the logic?

Answer (score 3):

Your code works if the provided strings are at least 6 characters long and contain a valid date. If the strings are shorter, you are reading out of bounds, and this can potentially cause your program to crash, or, even worse, it could silently return incorrect results. The YYMMDD format has a Y2K problem, and in many countries DDMMYY or MMDDYY are more commonly used arrangements, so someone not knowing the correct order could give your function incorrect data. Sometimes it's also hard to see how many consecutive spaces you have types, this can lead to hard to diagnose errors as well.

For these reasons, I strongly recommend that you don't pass dates around as strings. Instead, use an appropriate type that represents a date. C++20 introduced [`std::chrono::year_month_day`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day) and [`std::chrono::month_day`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/month_day); these would be great fits for your code. If you cannot use C++20 yet, you can use [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

Answer (score 2):

`cout`, `boolalpha` and `endl` are not declared.  You probably intended to include `<iostream>` and use `std::cout`, `std::boolalpha` and `std::endl` respectively.

I would recommend using one of the many available test frameworks to more thoroughly test the function.  A single test doesn't give very much confidence, and this function is highly amenable to automated unit-testing.   That will also help communicate when result is expected when `searchDate` is exactly equal to one of the boundary dates (note that C++ programmers will expect the test to be `start ≤ searchDate < end`, as that's how bounds are normally specified in this language).

The functions read very much like C code rather than C++.  I would expect strings to be passed as `std::string_view` rather than as C-style strings.  And we should be checking for end-of-string as we go, rather than running blindly past `\0`.

Instead of doubling up on the test logic, it's probably simpler to quickly decide whether the span crosses a year boundary, and swap both the bounds and the sense of the test.  With suitable types, that looks like

```
    bool inclusive = start < end;
    if (!inclusive) {
        std::swap(start, end);
    }
    return (start <= searchDate && searchDate < end) == inclusive;
```

`compareParial` is a strange name; did you intend to write "partial", rather than "parial"?